# Same list address in memory for two different instantiations of the class

Tags: python, list, class, memory

I have the following code:

```
class PWA_Parse():
    include = []

    def appendInclude(self, element):
        self.include.append(element)

    def printMemory(self):
        print "Class location", hex(id(self)), "List location:", hex(id(self.include))

a = PWA_Parse()
b = PWA_Parse()

a.appendInclude(5)

a.printMemory()
b.printMemory()
```

The list memory address for both are the same:

```
Class location 0x29e9788 List location: 0x29e95d0    
Class location 0x29e97b0 List location: 0x29e95d0
```

How could I create a list in the class definition in order to get two separate lists on instantiation? 
(Hint: I tried with list() already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring `include` as a class variable you are making all instances of this class share the same variable `include`.

Instead, you should make `include` an instance variable by initializing it in the `__init__()` method:

```
class PWA_Parse():
    def __init__(self):
        self.include = []
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list in the `__init__` method, which automatically gets called after instantiation.